# Defaulting dependencies

Tags: c#

What are some advantages and disadvantages of providing default implementations for dependencies. I have chosen to do this because it allows the objects to be easily used in the application but also allows me to mock for unit testing.

```
public class RoleProvider : RoleProviderBase
{
    private IRoleDataProvider _roleDataProvider;

    private IEntitlementsDataProvider EntitlementsDataProvider
    {
        get
        {
            if (_roleDataProvider == null)
            {
                _roleDataProvider = new RoleDataProvider();
            }
            return _roleDataProvider;
        }
    }

    public RoleProvider(IRoleDataProvider roleDataProvider)
    {
        _roleDataProvider = roleDataProvider;
    }

    public RoleProvider()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is very practical and makes it much easier to reuse the class. It's also easy to test or even substitute very different implementations of composite components on demand in production code.
However, I do have a few suggestions worth considering when doing this sort of thing.

**There's no need to code the substitution mechanism until you actually need it for your first test.**

So start out with only the parameterless constructor.
Until then, the additional code would just be clutter. (I.e. don't add stuff automatically just because you might need it.)

**The lazy initialization approach you used isn't thread-safe, so you may want to consider coding the parameterless constructor as follows.**

This is of course assuming that the either the composite object will always be used or is 'cheap' to construct. Otherwise you might want to look into a thread-safe lazy initialization technique or ensure the object is not shared across multiple threads.

```
public RoleProvider()
{
  _roleDataProvider = new RoleDataProvider();
}
```

**Watch out for the possibility of circular dependencies.**

A typical programming problem is handling circular dependencies. This technique can be exposed to that risk, because you're not explicitly specifying the dependencies at construction time. E.g.

```
new A(); //automatically creates default B which automatically creates default A etc.
```

Whereas forcing the composite object to be provided in the constructor avoids the risk.

```
//Assuming X and B share a common ancestor which 
//is required as input to A's constructor.
x = new X(); //Truly doesn't have composite objects.
a1 = new A(x);
b = new B(a1);
a1 = new A(b);
```

Note that it's impossible to code infinite circular construction dependencies this way.

Answer (score 5):

I personally don't see any problem with this (maybe someone else might provide better insight) but in this situation I do tend to do it differently but instantiating it via constructor overloading and making the private field readonly.

e.g.

```
public class RoleProvider : RoleProviderBase
{
    private readonly IRoleDataProvider _roleDataProvider;

    public RoleProvider()
       : this(new RoleDataProvider())
    {
    }

    public RoleProvider(IRoleDataProvider roleDataProvider)
    {
        _roleDataProvider = roleDataProvider;
    }
}
```

Perhaps this question might be better asked on PE as well?